# Can I have two sets of vertex colors for a Unity mesh?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, vertex-shader

I need a mesh with two sets of vertex colors so that I can interpolate between them in my shader. For a `color4` I need all of its four components.

`Mesh` seems having only one color array. Can I have multiple sets of colors?

I find that I haven't use `Mesh.tangents` which contains `Vector4` elements. But I have to convert `Color` array to `Vector4` array if I use this as a color array. Are there better ideas?

Comment: Try TEXCOORD1 for that

Comment: Thanks. I searched about TEXCOORD1, and find here https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-VertexProgramInputs.html, it says TEXCOORDx can be `float2`, `float3` or `float4`, but in C# I can only pass `Vector2`s in `SetUVs()`.

Comment: use TEXCOORD1 and TEXCOORD2. you can do tc1.x,tc1.y,tc2.x,tc2.y = r,g,b,a

Comment: Another option would be to put this data in [MaterialPropertyBlock](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MaterialPropertyBlock.SetFloatArray.html) and read it from there.